# Why did Sylvester Stallone empty and reload his gun?

Tags: tango-and-cash

At the beginning of [Tango and Cash (1989)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tango_%26_Cash) Sylvester Stallone pulls ahead of a getaway oil tanker to stop the criminals driving it by shooting at them.

As he preps for this, he pulls out his revolver and dumps all the unfired bullets currently in the gun on the ground only to refill it with more bullets. **Why does he do this?**

My best guess is he's switching between regular bullets and hollow-points but even if that's the case, I don't understand why he would prefer one or the other in that situation, nor can I tell for sure which one he's switching to.

Comment: hmmmm, interesting question.  He shoots at the windshield of the truck, but the bullets do not penetrate the windshield.  Maybe he switched ammunition because he just wanted to scare the perpetrators, which worked.

Comment: Huh that's not a bad theory. Maybe he switched to rubber slugs or something to make sure he didn't kill them or something...

Comment: The bullets do penetrate the side of the truck at 2:29.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Detective Ray Tango is armed with a [Smith & Wesson Model 36](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Tango_%26_Cash#Smith_.26_Wesson_Model_36_.22Chief.27s_Special.22) "Chief's Special" in this particular scene in the movie.

According to [imfdb](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Tango_%26_Cash), Tango empties his ammunition and re-loads with blanks.

The reasoning is not explained, but he aims for the perpetrators' driving the oil tanker to try and stop them, but not kill them.

[image: Tango & Cash]

> Tango aims his 36. It is **clearly loaded with blanks since the bullet**
>   **heads aren't visible in the front of the chambers.**

Comment: Awesome I didn't know that site even existed. Thanks.

Comment: @sanpaco it is a very good resource pertaining to the use of firearms in films :)

Comment: Er, not that I'm an expert, but don't they mean that they're visibly blanks because *it's a prop*? Would blanks really make [this kind of impact](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsGq4_19p6Q#t=02m00s) on a windshield from that distance?

Comment: @Walt Well, it depends on the type of load that the blank has.  A blank can be loaded with anything from rubber to wadded up paper.  You can load a blank with some sort of dense rubber material and if it is loaded with enough gunpowder, it can put a dent in a car or crack your windshield in this case.  Brandon Lee was killed by a blank round on the set of _The Crow_ , so they can still be dangerous.

Comment: Per my answer below, you can see the round when he puts them into the gun for a split-second. Since they aren't visible in the next scene, this is obviously down to a (out of universe) decision to replace them with blanks rather than happening in universe. You aren't supposed to be able to see them that closely!

Comment: @Richard Pfft!  Thanks for crushing my hopes and dreams on which type of blanks that he was actually firing ;)

Comment: @steelerfan - I think i've identified the bullet-type. They're "[less than lethal](http://www.conceptsinammunition.com/Pistol_Products/9mm.htm)" rounds, commonly used by householders and target shooters

Comment: @Richard You definitely did!  I was just messing with you :)  GO STEELERS!

Comment: @steelerfan - There's some more background info about the film here that might interest you...http://tinyurl.com/tangoandcash

Comment: @Richard arghhh!  I can't believe that I fell for that!!  Good one :)

Comment: I am not so sure this explains it. Being a movie, the gun will be loaded with blanks regardless of what occurs in-universe. While it is likely he switch to nonlethal rounds in-universe, the visibility of bullet tips from a front-shot of the revolver straddles both in- and out-of-universe.

Comment: @Snowman I believe that it's self-explanatory that since it's a movie, he is obviously going to have blanks out of universe.  I guess I am trying to understand your point.

Comment: @steelerfan my point is exactly what I said: the fact that they look like blanks is weak evidence because they _have_ to be blanks.

Comment: @Snowman ok, but Hollywood uses blanks all of the time that have the appearance of a live round.  Why would they purposely show us that they are blanks unless it's both in and out of universe?

Comment: @steelerfan - The only reason you can see that the gun is filled with blanks is because modern players and dvd quality video allows you to. Also, 99% of viewers wouldn't notice.

Comment: @Richard Well, even if you can't actually see the blanks, the only logical deduction that can be made is that they were used since they made it a point of showing him unload live rounds.  Oh yeah, Steelers defeated Bengals on Sunday!!!

Answer (score 13):

In-universe, the reasoning seems to be that he's unloaded his normal ammo and replaced it with bullets that will *damage the windscreen* without actually killing the perps inside. He then stands in the middle of the road and carefully fires at the glass. When he refuses to move, the villains are forced to brake sharply and they fly through the (**now-weakened**) windshield to land on the road in front of him.

**Note the white tips. They appear to be some sort of clear plastic "[less than lethal](http://www.conceptsinammunition.com/Pistol_Products/38cal.htm)" target round**
[image]

Quite why he's carrying this particular style of bullet is never explained but then again, the film went through three screenwriters (at least one of whom wanted to make the film into a slapstick comedy), two directors, two cinematographers and five(!) editors before it hit the big screen so it's very possible that his reasoning simply got cut out.

Comment: I'm assuming he was carrying target-shooting rounds because he was on his way to target practice when the call came in the the drug-smugglers had been spotted.

Comment: That being said, it's not at all clear why the next shot went clean through the metal wall of the tanker.

Comment: If you're target-shooting, you'll either use regular bullets or flat-fronted [wadcutter bullets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadcutter).

Comment: @Mark - Tell that to the makers of those plastic bullets..."*Target and trick shooters will appreciate our true flight technology. Choose target load ammo for your weapon and not only will you be able to shoot safely, but accurately both indoors and out."*

Comment: Most people use FMJ rounds at the range due to cost, but self-defense rounds when carrying (which cost a _lot_ more). However, one should practice at least some of the time with whatever rounds one carries in the firearm because different rounds may have different recoil.

Comment: @Snowman - What kind of bullet would you use to blow a hole in the side of a fuel tanker filled with cocaine?

Comment: @Richard a cannonball.

Answer (score -3):

He was getting rid of the anti-personnel rounds for armor piercing or long distance heavy hitting rounds. This was homage to the Jackie Chan Movie "Police Story".

Comment: This contradicts the other answers, which suggest he was loading in *less* lethal bullets, not *more* lethal ones. Can you provide any evidence that those were in fact the kinds of rounds he chambered, and that this was done as a Jackie Chan homage?

Answer (score -4):

If you listen carefully when he emptys the 38.....its shell casings that he dumps out...they sound completely hollow.

Comment: Not so...you can see clearly that they are complete shells including bullets as they hit the ground. Why would he carry around a gun with empty shells in it?